# Simplify Big O notation

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I apologize in advance for my poor math skills...

I'm trying to understand how the math behind Big O Notation works.  I understand from [this](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~atat/473/lecture02.pdf) that `2n^2 = O(n^3)` and have proved that `n = O(n^2)`, but I also seem to have proved that `n^3 = O(n^2)` which doesn't make sense and I'm pretty sure is wrong.  Here's how I'm "proving" this:

```
n^3 = O(n^2)
n^3 <= c*n^2
n <= c     #n^2 cancels out
1 <= c/n
c = 1; n0 = 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1 is not less than, e.g., 1/10000 (when n = 10000 >= 1 = n0).

Comment: You have to satisfy it for all n>n0,  Clearly, n<=c is a contradiction.

Comment: I see what I'm doing wrong now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 <= c/n` does not hold for all `n > n0`, for example, for n=2 (with your n0=1,c=1), you get:

```
1 <= 1/2
```

and this is a false statement.

The key in big O notation is you need to prove that for ALL `n > n0`, the equation `f(n) <= C*g(n)` holds (for some `C,n0`) , in order to show `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))`

Comment: Ah, I forgot that key bit about "All `n > n0`".  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Normally Big O notation is defined as a set of functions with common asymptotic behaviour. That is, as n grow large how will the function grow.

In this case, we clearly see that n^3 outgrows n^2, so they are in fact in different O classes.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `What am I doing wrong?`